# Hover on `li`, change the next one's style?

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar.
Each item has borders on the right side (execpt the 1st one, which has borders on left and right).

I'm looking for a way to hide the next/previous `li`'s right border, disallowing a duplicate border.

[image]

You can see a lighter border on the right side of the first item.
I would need to hide the 1st item's right border or hide the 2nd one's left border, and instead activate the right side of the 1st one.

I was looking through the CSS selectors, but couldn't find pretty much anything.

Almost all the selectors are for selecting a child from parent.

---

### CSS

```
#nav {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
margin-top: 25px;
z-index: 9;
left: 0;
display: inline;
text-align: center;
}

#nav li {
list-style: none;
display: inline;
padding: 7px;
margin-left: 2px;
margin-right: 2px;
height: 100%;
border-right: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
transition: 0.2s ease;
}

#nav li:nth-of-type(1) {
border-left: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
}


#nav li:hover:nth-of-type(1) {
border-left: 2px solid #C4C4C4;
border-right: 2px solid #C4C4C4;
}

#nav li:hover:nth-of-type(2){
border-left: 2px solid #C4C4C4;
border-right: 2px solid #C4C4C4;
}

#nav li:hover:nth-of-type(2) #nav li:nth-of-type(1){
border-left: 0px solid transparent;
}
```

### HTML

```
<nav id="nav">
<li>Etusivu</li>
<li>Tietoa Meistä</li>
<li>Hinnasto</li>
<li>Yhteystiedot</li>
</nav>
```

---

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4f8m1jdp/)

Sorry for the messy explanation.

Comment: You're code is ok for what you're trying to do, but you're missing a comma for your last pseduoselector: `#nav li:hover:nth-of-type(2)
#nav li:nth-of-type(1)`, and this is breaking your CSS. You need `#nav li:hover:nth-of-type(2)`,`#nav li:nth-of-type(1){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## http://jsfiddle.net/qp6sd0hc/

give -7px margin-left to nav li because by default display inline give some margin between elements

```
 nav li{ margin-left: -7px; }
```

Comment: Any suqqestions how to get rid of the 1px offsets when hovering on the items?

Comment: Just play with margins and padding if you want to !